# Why is this returning 'Undefined?'

Tags: javascript, macos, node.js, readline

I'm learning some of nodes core modules and i've wrote a little command line tool to test out the `readline` module but on my `console.log()` outputs, i'm also recieving `undefined` under it :/

Here's my code..

```
var rl = require('readline');

var prompts = rl.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);

prompts.question("What is your favourite Star Wars movie? ", function (movie) {

    var message = '';

    if (movie = 1) {
        message = console.log("Really!!?!?? Episode" + movie + " ??!?!!?!?!, Jar Jar Binks was a total dick!");
    } else if (movie > 3) {
        message = console.log("They were great movies!");
    } else {
        message = console.log("Get out...");
    }

  console.log(message);

  prompts.close();
});
```

And here's what im seeing in my console..

```
What is your favourite Star Wars movie? 1
Really!!?!?? Episode1 ??!?!!?!?!, Jar Jar Binks was a total dick!
undefined
```

Why am I getting back `undefined`?

Comment: What did you expect it to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why am I getting back `undefined`?

Because `console.log` doesn't have a return value, so you're assigning `undefined` to `message`.

Since you're outputting `message` later, just remove the `console.log` calls from the lines where you're setting the message. E.g., change

```
message = console.log("Really!!?!?? Episode" + movie + " ??!?!!?!?!, Jar Jar Binks was a total dick!");
```

to

```
message = "Really!!?!?? Episode" + movie + " ??!?!!?!?!, Jar Jar Binks was a total dick!";
```

---

Side note: Your line

```
if (movie = 1) {
```

**assigns** the number `1` to `movie` and then tests the result (`1`) to see if it's truthy. So no matter what you type in, it will always take that branch. You probably meant:

```
if (movie == 1) {
```

...although I would recommend *not* relying on implicit type coercion of user-supplied input, and so I'd put this near the top of that callback:

```
movie = parseInt(movie, 10);
```

Comment: @mplungjan: Indeed, worth noting.

Comment: Ha, derp.. of course.. also I was console.log'ing the contents of message which in itself was assigned a console.log statement!

My code now reads the below and it's fine.

var rl = require('readline');

var prompts = rl.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);

prompts.question("What is your favourite Star Wars movie? ", function (movie) {

 if (movie = 1) {
  console.log("Really!!?!?? Episode" + movie + " ??!?!!?!?!, Jar Jar Binks was a total dick!");

 } else if (movie > 3) {
  console.log("They were great movies!");
 } else {
  console.log("Get out...");
 };

  prompts.close();
});

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` doesn't return a value, so the result is `undefined`.

Note: comparison is done with `==`, eg: `movie == 1`.